# WiFi network is not saved when phone is rebooted

Tags: wi-fi

I recently rooted my Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ and have found that every time I reboot my phone, I have to re enter my home WiFi network password again. I checked my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in `/data/misc/wifi` and found that when I connect to my WiFi network it is saved to the file but when I reboot, it disappears. The strange part is that other WiFi networks I have previously connected to remain in the file. This is what the the file has for my WiFi network after I connect:

```
network={
    ssid="My Wifi 5GHz"
    psk=7281996584ae07843694243231a22d0d
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=15
    frequency=5180
    autojoin=1
    usable_internet=0
    skip_internet_check=0
    verified_password=1
}
```

What's the issue and how do I fix it? Thanks.